# Change a datarow item from DBNull to a string value

Tags: c#, asp.net, datatable, datarow

I may be doing this all wrong, but here goes:

```
    OleDbDataAdapter adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM [CRPRList$]", XLSConnect);
    //the XLSConnect is from a spreadsheet. I've confirmed the data is there.
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    adapter.Fill(ds);
    DataTable thisTable = ds.Tables[0];
    //The table exists and it does populate
    thisTable.Columns.Add("Summary");
    //The new column is added and I am able to populate it (below)

    for (int rowNum = 0; rowNum < thisTable.Rows.Count; rowNum++) { 
        //Here I'm cycling through the row items

        DataRow row = thisTable.Rows[rowNum];
        string pr = row["PR"].ToString();
        string cr = row["CR"].ToString();
        //The first two column values are grabbed and examined

        if ((pr != "" && pr != null)&&(cr == null || cr == "")) {
           //if the first column is empty then the second is examined and I am attempting
           //to populate the first column using the searchForCRNumber method
           //This method returns a string

            cr = this.searchForCRNumber(pr); //assignment works
            row[0] = cr; //Here is the problem, this assignment does not work (more explained below)
        }
        row["Summary"] = this.searchForSummary(cr);
        row.AcceptChanges();
    }
    this.showResults(thisTable);//works, except the changes above are not applied
```

The line `row[0] = cr;` is naturally an empty value and so it comes up as type `DBNull` and won't accept  `cr` string.

The error I'm getting is `System.FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format.`

I've searched for ways to convert `row[0]` to an empty string or some other way to cast the `cr` and so far I've not found a way to do this.

**EDIT** *I'm adding more to help understand what is going on around this problem. I thought I was thorough enough above, but perhaps not...*

The data for `XLSConnect` comes from:

```
private bool XSLConnection(string filePath, string fileType) { // returns false if XSL or XSLX is not the fileType
    string strConn;
    if (fileType.ToLower() == "xls" || fileType.ToLower() == "xlsx") {
        strConn = (fileType == "xlsx") ? string.Format("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source={0};Extended Properties=\"Excel 12.0\"", filePath) : string.Format("Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source={0};Extended Properties=\"Excel 8.0\"", filePath);

        XLSConnect = new OleDbConnection(strConn);
        return true;
    } else return false;
}
```

Here's the `searchForCRNumber` method:

```
private string searchForCRNumber(string PRNumber) {
    return this.getProperty("MyReturnColumn", PRNumber, "MyMatchColumn");
}
```

And here's the `getProperty` method:

```
private string getProperty(string searchProperty, string searchVal, string rtrnProperty) {
    string undefined = "Undefined";
    string rtrn = null;
    string query = "SELECT " + rtrnProperty + " FROM MySQLTable WHERE " + searchProperty + " = '" + searchVal + "'";
    this.QCConn.Open();

    SqlDataReader reader = this.runQCConnect(query).ExecuteReader();
    reader.Read();
    rtrn = (!reader.HasRows)?
        undefined :
        reader[0].ToString();

    if (rtrn == "" || rtrn == null) rtrn = undefined;
    this.QCConn.Close();


    return rtrn;
}
```

**MORE Edit**
I'm still working on this one and I'm begining to wonder if I have not found a bug. I have found what is wrong and am still working on a way to fix it. The xls(x) that is uploaded can have empty cells. I've found that those empty cells will cause the DataTable to have empty cells but their type is DBNull... which, of course, can't (naturally) be assigned a string value.

When I apply the following in a try/catch:

```
throw new Exception("PR = " + pr + " and typeof = " + pr.GetType().ToString() + " && CR = " + cr + " and typeof = " + cr.GetType().ToString() + "\nCell typeof = " + row["CR"].GetType().ToString());
```

I get this response:

```
PR = 7800 and typeof = System.String && CR = Undefined and typeof = System.String
Cell typeof = System.DBNull
```

So as you can see, the cell is System.DBNull and won't accept a string value. This is the source of my error. But I still do not know how to make this work. Is there something I'm missing? How can I assign the string value to these cells regardless of the DBNull value?

Comment: can you post the searchForCRNumber(pr) procedure?

Comment: `row[0] = cr; ` Here is not the problem. This cannot cause that exception.

Comment: I can, however, I it does return a string as expected. The point should be moot.

Comment: row[0] comes up as type `DBNull` while cr comes up as type `string`. And here is where debugging shows the problem

Comment: @Jimmmy: However, you are  not returning the indexed property, you are setting it. That can cause [several exceptions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5akhx035.aspx) but not  a `FormatException`.

Comment: @TimSchmelter: If that is the case, then how can I change the value of row[0] before it is used to fill a GridView (which is where, ultimately, all this goes in `showResults`)?

Comment: I think I need to get the DataSet to not allow DBNull, or to allow them but make them string... Heck, I'm still figuring this out

Answer (score 2):

`DBNull` is not a null string, and converting it to a string will not give you `null`.

If that's what you want, you should probably check for that before converting it to a string. Do something like:

```
string pr = (row["PR"] == System.DBNull.Value) ? null : row["PR"].ToString();
string cr = (row["CR"] == System.DBNull.Value) ? null : row["CR"].ToString();
```

Comment: this still does not change the type DBNull of row[0] and the error persists

Comment: @Jimmmy, I suspect your definition of `row[0]` does not allow nulls; tell us what the properties of `row.Table.Columns[0]` are.

Comment: OK, maybe this is the right direction. I'm new to using `DataSet` and all the properties that I've given it are already showing. The only other thing to add is that the data is coming from a spreadsheet where empty cells are possible.

Comment: @Jimmmy tell us all properties of all columns of `thisTable`. We cannot help you without this information. The number of possible problems is enormous (wrong number of columns, invalid values, nonunique values, conflicting data types, key violations, constraint violations, triggers, many more...)

Comment: It's all in the original post. I guess you could say I've left everything default(??).

Comment: @Jimmy, your original post contains none of the information we need. The default column type is a nullable string, so if your row is not accepting one that cannot be its data type. The fact you sometimes use a column name (`row["PR"]`) and sometimes an index (`row[0]`) is also very suspicious.

Comment: Well, then it may be that I need to come up with a completely different approach... The difference between column names and indexes was something I've already updated. The indexes matched the input column names before and changing them did not make a difference. The code above is the sum-total of the code I'm using RE: this issue. If I can't understand this problem then perhaps I should find another way to accomplish the same thing: upload, examine, and update (if needed) data from an xsl(x) sheet.