# Best way to substitute empty string for DBNull?

Tags: .net, vb.net, if-statement, datarow, dbnull

If a column in a `DataRow` might be `DBNull`, is the following the shortest way to substitute an empty string for `DBNull`?

```
Dim result As String = if(isDBNull(dataRow1("column1")), "", dataRow1("column1"))
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Change a datarow item from DBNull to a string value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15507675/change-a-datarow-item-from-dbnull-to-a-string-value)

Comment: That does not look like valid C#. I think you want to use the ternary operator "? :" for that.

Answer (score 2):

`dataRow1("column1") & ""` will produce the desired result in VB.

Comment: This will not work in typesafe code (with `OPTION STRICT ON`)

Answer (score 1):

Just use the [`Field(Of T)` methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb360891.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb), which will convert `DBNull` values to `Nothing` for you. Also, they are typesafe.

```
Dim result = If(dataRow1.Field(Of String)("column1"), String.Empty)
```

Answer (score 0):

you might want to create an extension method for ease of use (not tested):

```
Imports System.Data
Imports System.Runtime.CompilerServices

Module Extensions
    <Extension()>
    Public Function GetStringValue(dataRow As DataRow, columnName As String, Optional substituesForDBNull As String = Nothing) As String
        If IsDBNull(dataRow(columnName)) Then
            Return substituesForDBNull
        End If
        Return CStr(dataRow(columnName))
    End Function
End Module
```